# dataSnapShot.getChildren() returning null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch the user details of a particular user using a query:

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child("user_account_settings"))
            .orderByChild("user_id")
            .equalTo(getItem(position).getUser_id());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: the fetched user id is " + getItem(position).getUser_id());
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                //do stuff
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[Firebase database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydKR9.jpg)

The user id that is fetched is correct according to the database and it clearly has children, but for some reason `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` is empty thus not allowing me to iterate through the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that the user ID property is called in the database `userid`, while in your query you are using `user_id`, which is incorrect. The name of the field in your query must match the name field in the database. To solve this, simply change:

```
.orderByChild("user_id")
```

To:

```
.orderByChild("userid")
```